# Error when when creating Derived Class constructor

Tags: c++, opengl, inheritance

I'm making a game (in OpenGL/SDL) where there are general Entities and specific objects which are derived from the Entity class. I have one such derived class for the bullets. Here are the definitions for the Entity and Bullet classes:

```
class Entity {
public:
    Entity(ShaderProgram program): program(program){}
    void Draw() {

    }
    void Update(float elapsed) {
        // move stuff and check for collisions
    }
    void Render() {
        // for all game elements
        // setup transforms, render sprites
    }
    float x;
    float y;
    float rotation;
    int textureID;
    float width;
    float height;
    float speed;
    float direction_x;
    float direction_y;
    ShaderProgram program;
    GLuint spriteSheetTexture = LoadTexture("sheet.png");
    SheetSprite mySprite = SheetSprite(spriteSheetTexture, 241.0f / 1024.0f, 941.0f / 1024.0f, 99.0f / 1024.0f, 75.0f /1024.0f, 0.2, program);
};

class Bullet : public Entity {
public:

    Bullet(ShaderProgram program, float angle, float timeAlive) : program(program), angle(angle), timeAlive(timeAlive){}

    float angle;
    float timeAlive;
    ShaderProgram program;
};
```

As derived classes don't inherit constructors, I made another constructor (initializing the same program as the base class) for the bullet class. For some reason, I'm getting the pre-compilation error: `No default constructor exists for class "Entity"`  on the open brace after the initialization list in the derived class.

It could just be that I've been looking at the code for too long, but I'm fairly certain that I've initialized everything in the derived class properly, and there isn't any default constructor being used. What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you explicitly provide parameters for the base class constructor, the base class's default constructor is used.  You want this:

```
Bullet(ShaderProgram program, float angle, float timeAlive) : 
Entity(program), angle(angle), timeAlive(timeAlive) {}
```

And you probably don't want `program` in the derived class, since it is inherited from Entity.

Comment: Oh ok, but doesn't default constructor mean the constructor that gets used when none is specified? And also, just to confirm, anytime you specify a derived class constructor where variables from the base class need to be initialized, you should use the base class to initialize the variables right (e.g. ```Entity(program)```)

Comment: @loremIpsum1771: A default constructor is one that can be called with no parameters.  And yes, you should typically let the base class initialize the base class's members instead of trying to initialize them in the derived class.

Comment: So basically, if the base class has non-empty ctor parameters, then the corresponding parameters in the derived class have to be initialized by the base class ctor.